# Planning a UX road map for a re-design

Tags: web, maps, style

I'm planning on re-designing my company's app and I want some help with the what and why.

I need to create a road map document and to approximate the hours it will take me to research, create a style guide and later, to implement it.

Where to start?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a very general question. Could you break it up into more specific questions? Questions like "where to start with UX design" should really just be googled.

Comment: I'd recommend you to take a look to Agile planning methodologies, specially stories and points. Whether you use Agile or not, will help you understand how to get time approximations for projects

Answer (score 1):

## Identify types of views

This is just a visual redesign, right? You'll need to align with product initiatives and potentially solve some interaction problems at the same time, but a visual redesign is less involved than a feature enhancement.

This is roughly how I would approach it.

1. Break the views into like categories, eg views that share templates or follow the same pattern.
2. Work with the Product Manager / Owner to identify your highest priority views and look for any other changes they'd like to make at the same time.
3. Work with Engineering to consider the estimated complexity of modifying each view type and validate that you've correctly identified like things.
4. Estimate your time to research, develop, and user test designs for each key view within the general types. You'll be establishing a pattern to follow.
5. Compare the intersection of product value, engineering effort, design effort, and business alignment for each view to create your priority list.

Answer (score 0):

You could start by listing all of the changes you are taking into consideration to get the big picture. Categorize them by priority and how much time you think each point will require (just an approximation). From there, you can get an overall idea of the work that needs to be done. Later break down each point into the elements and details to understand specific requirements. I usually work some sketches in parallel to get a better and more detailed idea of what will need to be done.